# Tell the compiler to translate a certain instruction differently?

Tags: c, gcc, arm, embedded

I'm using ***armcc*** and ***arm-gcc*** for compiling my project for an ARM968 processor.
When returning form a function call, the returning instruction is as follows:

```
Pop {ri-rj, pc}
```

All the pushed registers are popped in the same instruction. I want to change the instruction above into something like this:

```
Pop {ri-rj}
Pop {pc}
```

Can I instruct the assembler or the compiler to adhere to the rule above in any of the ARM tool chains when using `Pop`?

Comment: No, you can't.. Why would you want to do that anyway?

Comment: you can do it in assembly of course, and gcc is open source so you can change that.  But there is nothing target specific in the C language itself, a compiler may have some feature, but it isnt necessarily going to cross from one toolchain to another.

Comment: Note the compiler is generating instructions not translating them.  The assembler would translate them, and you could attack the problem there with gnu assembler since it is open source.  but not generically.

Comment: you could generically write your own tool that runs between the compiler and the assembler and then you can modify anything you want.

Comment: Hey Eugene. I'm working with custom hardware. The current format of the instruction seems to operate erroneously on the current hardware. When I breakdown the instruction, as stated above, it works. I'm trying to find a work around for this hardware problem.

Comment: Hey @dwelch. Thanks a lot for the info. I've started to look at the **Machine Description** files for GCC regarding my underlying architecture; it seems to be a possible solution. I'm looking for straight forward solutions, if possible, before jumping into GCC intricacies.

Comment: You can't modify `armcc`, of course.. The best solution would be to fix you HW, as who knows what other problems it might lead to (telling you as someone having a HW problem on ARM core and using armcc :) )? But I like the workaround @StianSkjelstad provided below, as it fits `armcc` as well.

Comment: @Winston, approach with care, gcc is held together with duct tape and bailing wire, one wrong move and it all crumbles.   While in there you may find that there may already be a switch for some arm variants that do what you want.  for example they might generate a bx lr instead of a pop pc as they do not do the same thing for all architectures.

Comment: that is what I meant by writing your own tool that runs between the compiler and assembler.  sure you could use existing ascii manipulation programs too.

Comment: also understand that pop is not a real arm instruction (for an arm9) ldm is/was used, so some tools may show the ascii as ldmia instead of pop. and the older tools didnt use ldmia they used/generated ldmfd.   so ldmfd then ldmia and now either ldmia or pop or sometimes just ldm depending...so check your solution against all the tools you want to use and their command line options.  when pop came along in thumb the tools started tolerating it for full sized arms.  in both cases it just generates the ldm instruction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can tell gcc to stop processing after it has generated the assembler. The you can edit the assembler files manually or by using `sed`. Then you pass the assembler file to `as` from binutils to assemble it into an object file.

```
$ cat test.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        printf ("hello world\n");

        return 0;
}
$ gcc test.c -o test.s -S
cat test.s
        .file   "test.c"
        .section        .rodata
.LC0:
        .string "hello world"
        .text
        .globl  main
        .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        pushq   %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        .cfi_offset 6, -16
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
        subq    $16, %rsp
        movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
        movq    %rsi, -16(%rbp)
        movl    $.LC0, %edi
        call    puts
        movl    $0, %eax
        leave
        .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
        .size   main, .-main
        .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.8.4"
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
$ as test.s -o test.o
```

Comment: Thanks @StianSkjelstad. I've got 2 questions regarding manually editing compiler outputs:
**1-** In this particular case, I have to modify all the instances of **pop**, breaking them into 2 different instructions. Could this cause the **code section** to be oversized and therefore trimmed by the tool chain during **linkage**? The output format is **ARM ELF** which brings me to my second question.
**2-** How can you manually change the size of different sections of an **ARM ELF** file? Is this "good practice"?

Comment: 1) It will get assembled before linkage, so you will get warnings if something is wrong with it. 2) You can modify a linker script/scatter file.

Comment: Sections does normally not have a fixed size, they just grow as bytes are added into them, and the linker script when linking to a executable or library in the end can force sections to merge, reorder them, discard them, pad them up page sizes etc. Most people just let the linker use its default settings here

Comment: no you dont need to worry about the code section being oversized any more than you would adding code in the high level language.  the compiler makes as much code as it makes, if you make a slight amount more, so be it, the amount generated is not determined or checked until you assemble it.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the exact nature of the problem, and whether you're critically dependent on a handful of newer instructions, another possibility *might* be to compile for ARMv4T. Prior to ARMv5T, `ldm` into the PC was not interworking, so the compiler won't emit that form of return instruction for a v4T target. For some simple test code, compiling with `-march=armv5t` generates a stack frame thus:

```
   8:   e92d4070        push    {r4, r5, r6, lr}
...
  4c:   d8bd8070        pople   {r4, r5, r6, pc}
```

whereas compiling the same thing with `-march=armv4t` uses the same prologue but with an indirect return sequence (the above was a conditional return from inside a loop, now it's also moved out to the end of the function):

```
  48:   da000006        ble     68 <func+0x68>
...
  68:   e8bd4070        pop     {r4, r5, r6, lr}
  6c:   e12fff1e        bx      lr
```

Of course, whether that has the same effect as the two separate pops depends on what the underlying bug in the system is - if it's something like the timing between the data fetches of the `ldm` and the instruction fetches of the jump itself, then this might be sufficiently equivalent; it could conceivably be something quite different, like a broken memory system truncating AHB bursts above a certain size, so it's the number of registers transferred in a single `ldm` that's the issue, but in that case I'd also expect to see problems with things like `memcpy` which aren't so easily fixed.